# Get list of computers in a Workgroup using WMI VBScript

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I need get list of all computers in a WORKGROUP. I tried the

`Dim objComputers

Set objComputers = GetObject("WinNT://WORKGROUP")`

But it is Active Directory object. Is there any way to get the computers without `WinNT://`?

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the group object by using the full LDAP path.

```
Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & strGroupLDAP)
```

You can enumerate after with something like:

```
For Each strMachine In objGroup.Members
```

Refer to items by:

```
strMachine.Name or strMachine.samAccountName
```

EDIT: I'm confused by your question now that I reread it, what is the problem, you can use winnt:// to bind to either the domain or a machine?